# export string value in a registry

Tags: batch-file, registry

i want to export HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABC\EFGH string XYZ value 12. i looked into regedit /e and Reg export. it gives options to export till HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABC\EFGH, but not my string value XYZ.

Comment: i want to export subkeys only

Comment: I am not clear on what you want.  Do you want to actually export that registry setting for backup purposes so that you can restore it easily or do you want the value of that registry setting assigned to an environmental variable to be used later in a batch file?

Comment: i need it for backup and restore

Answer (score 0):

I can think of no native method of exporting just a particular value with its data directly as a `.reg` file.

The best advice would be that you parse the output from `reg query` for your particular value data, and save it as a `reg add` command to another batch file. Then when, or if, you need to replace that value data with the previously saved data, you can just run that saved batch file.

Below is a basic example, *(designed only for use with value type REG_SZ)*. I've used a common registry subkey and value for demonstration purposes, *(because yours was not clear to me)*; please replace those on lines `4` and `5` as per your specific requirements:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "RegistryKey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop"
Set "ValueName=Wallpaper"

Set "ValueData="
For /F "Tokens=*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "%RegistryKey%"
 /V "%ValueName%" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "\<REG_SZ\>"'
) Do (Set "ValLine=%%G" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1,*" %%H In ('!ValLine:*%ValueName%^=!'
    ) Do EndLocal & Set "ValueData=%%I")
If Defined ValueData Echo @%%SystemRoot%%\System32\reg.exe Add "%RegistryKey%"^
 /V "%ValueName%" /T REG_SZ /D "%ValueData:"=\"%" /F 1^>NUL 1>"%ValueName%.cmd"
```

If the string value is successfully found, its data will be saved to a local variable `%ValueData%`, *for further use within the script if required*. In addition, a batch file with the name of the registry value, should be output to the current directory. If you wish to change that name or location, please replace `%ValueName%.cmd` on the last line as needed. To restore the data at a later time just run the saved batch file.

Comment: i have a script, but heard there is native method to achieve this. tryied to figure it out

Comment: @sandeepshekar, please read my first sentence of the submission above. If you've heard that there is, then continue searching for it, and provide a link as part of an official answer to your own question, when you do. In the meantime, please create another answer, and post the script you have inside it, properly formatted, for use by the community. Thank you.

Comment: my req is export, make some changes to key and import it. @echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
regedit /e c:\temp\abc.txt SOFTWARE\ABC\EFGH
powershell.exe -Command "(gc c:\temp\cs.txt) -replace 'MNO', 'PQR' | Out-File -encoding ASCII c:\temp\abc.txt"
reg import c:\temp\abc.txt /reg:64

Comment: Unless your question is just very badly written, and unclear, @sandeepshekar, that is not what your question is about. Your question, by my understanding, was specifically asking about getting the content of a specific registry value, without all of the other subkeys and values along with it. That, as I said, cannot be natively done, so instead of a .reg file, to restore that value, this method used a batch file to restore it instead. The code above, saves your string value data, so that you can restore it later, by double clicking, or running directly in cmd, or a batch file, the saved `.cmd`